# iMessage not showing contacts' phone #s when texting- only their emails

Tags: iphone, email, contacts, text

I am using iOS 12.0.1 on an iphone 7. In iMessage, when I type in a contact name in "to," the person's email address will appear, and the phone number will NOT appear. iPhone will only give me the email address as an option. I have to go into the contacts list, find the person, and click on the message bubble to send a text from there. This happens repeatedly for certain contacts. I deleted their email addresses from my contacts list, hoping this would help, but now when I type their names from the "messages" screen, nothing shows up for them. I still have to go into contacts and text from there. This is particularly annoying when i want to do a group text.

Comment: SMS does not support group texts so group texts have to use email addresses

Comment: Mark, group texts work just fine with other contacts in my contact list. All these contacts have iPhones. Taylor

Comment: Do they se the messages as blue or green?

Comment: they see the messages as blue

Comment: So the messages are not sms so came via the Internet

Comment: The problem is not SMS or internet because the phone numbers of other contacts work just fine. There are a handful of contacts for whom iMessage will not display the phone number.

Comment: Why do you need to display the phone number? In iMessage, phone number = email address.